# How to count button clicks with lambda expression?

Tags: java, swing, lambda, jbutton

In this part of my code I want to count the amount of times the user has pressed the button. The problem is if I declare the number to count the clicks outside the function it doesn't go at all. Here is what I mean:

```
byte numButtonClicks = 0;

    tellingIntroButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        numButtonClicks ++;
        System.out.println(numButtonClicks);
    });
```

And declaring it inside is not an option either because than it will always be reset. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? It looks like you need to make your `numButtonClicks` a class member (I imagine it's currently defined inside a method).

Comment: Oh, okay that already is a good answer! I didn't knew that. I'll post again if that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like

```
public class YourComponent extends JFrame { // or whatever it is you're extending

    // ....

    public void init() {
        // ...
        byte numButtonClicks = 0;

        tellingIntroButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            numButtonClicks ++;
            System.out.println(numButtonClicks);
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

There are some problems you'll run into.

1. A variable used in an anonymous inner class (such as your action listener) must be implicitly final. The exception you mention in the comment on another answer,

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Local variable numButtonClicks defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
   ```

tells you that your counter variable isn't final

2. You're using a `byte` field for a counter. Why not an `int` or a `long`?
3. You can't declare a final `int` or `long` inside a method and increment it.

You can fix this either by having a member on your class, such as

```
public class YourComponent extends JFrame { // or whatever it is you're extending

    // ....

    private int numButtonClicks = 0;

    public void init() {
        // ...

        tellingIntroButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            YourComponent.this.numButtonClicks++;
            System.out.println(numButtonClicks);
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

or, a bit like the other answer suggests, if concurrency is an issue for you here (if the count can be modified by different threads), you can use a java8 object such as `LongAdder`. If you go this route (`LongAdder`) it needs to be declared **final** if you're declaring it within the scope of a method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let me know what is the exact error you are getting.If numButtonClicks is a local variable , you cant mutate over captured locals inside a lambda function . Make it a LongAdder  class variable  which is atomic and designed for concurrency.

```
  LongAdder numButtonClicks= new LongAdder();

              tellingIntroButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                    numButtonClicks.increment();
                    System.out.println(numButtonClicks);
                });
```

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Local variable numButtonClicks defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" That is the error message. I just don't really undstand what it wants from me.

Comment: Yeah the errors says you cannot change the value of local variables inside a lamda function . In your case you are changing it via incrementing numButtonClicks++. You  have to effectively create the variable in heap rather than in a function stack